# overflow:hidden works in Chrome 11, but not in firefox 4 or IE9

Tags: css

I am using http://tympanus.net/jPaginate/ to implement pagination.  Under Chrome 11, Demo 5 looks normal but under IE9 or Firefox 4, the last page number is shown and gets moved to a new line.

I think the div has overflow:hidden set so that the hidden page numbers are not supposed to be shown, unless ">>" or "<<" is mouseover.  This used to work properly in IE8 and Firefox 3.

How can I implement a workaround for IE9 and Firefox 4?

Comment: +1 I see the same behaviour on the linked page. You might try contacting the author http://tympanus.net/ to see if they have an update in the works, or maybe somebody here will come up with a fix that can be contributed back.

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed height to the div, otherwise it will stretch to accomodate all the content.

[EDIT]

Ah, it does not solve your issue, plus, seeing that the paginator is generated entirely by the plugin, I believe it's the plugin that is messing something up. It might also be that jQuery's `width()` function refuses to cooperate with FF4 and IE9. I happen to have a problem with `width()` resizing list elements in a nav menu on one of my sites, and it also happens with FF4 and IE9 only. Odd... You could try increasing the width of the `<ul>` containing the pagination elements with jQuery after generating the paginator, but that's a provisional solution.

Comment: jQuery's width is totally broken when the width is not an integer (so with any Firefox on Mac, Firefox 4+ on Windows, IE9+, and probably Firefo on Linux).

Comment: Say you have 30 things in a row each with a width of 10.3333px.  If you add up the width() of them all, you get 300px.  The correct width is 310px.  If you somehow got the rounded-up widths and added them you would get 330px.  In the end, if you want to compute widths for layout you really just need to use at least as much precision as the browser itself is using; otherwise you get weird artifacts.

Comment: I was rather thinking about rounding in the context of the pagination problem, where the issue you describe is not really applicable. But indeed, I understand your point.

Answer (score 0):

The page that you were referring to has the problem no longer.
I assume the element had `display:inline-block` property set -- that was the problem I had with my case.

To solve this case, you need to set `vertial-align` property.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align):

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box
>   in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if
>   its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in
>   which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

Answer (score 0):

Giving the `ul.jPag-pages li` element a fixed width solved my problem under ie9 and ie10